# Simultaneous equations confusion?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, algebraic-geometry, systems-of-equations

Given $ax+by=0$ and $cx+dy=0$ for some real numbers $a,b,c,d$ is it true that the only solutions are $x,y=0$? Does this mean that the two lines will not intersect I am quite confused on this matter.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, they intersect at the point $(0,0).$ Consider that if $ax+by=0$ then without loss of generality assume $a\ne 0,$ then $x=-\frac{b}{a}y,$ and similarly if $cx+dy=0,$ assuming $c\ne 0,$ you get $x=-\frac{d}{c}.$ Setting them equal to one another require that $\frac{b}{a}=\frac{d}{c},$ which in general will not be true. Since $(0,0)$ trivially satisfies both equations, and since the fore mentioned fractions must be equal otherwise, we have that $(0,0)$ is the only solution.

Answer (score 0):

This is usually the case. If $ax+by=0$, then $y=-\frac{a}{b}x$, and since we also have that $cx+dy=0$, we can substitute to get
$$cx-\frac{da}{b}x=0$$ and $x$ must be $0$, making $y$ also equal to zero. However, this is no the case if $a=kc$ and $b=kd$ where $k$ is some constant, because then the two lines are actually the same and have infinitely many solutions.

Answer (score 0):

Note that in all cases, $x = y = 0$ is a solution, so the equation $ax+by=0$ (provided at least one of $a$ or $b$ is nonzero) describes a line passing through the origin.

Hence we get the following cases:

1. The equations describe two distinct lines, hence they intersect precisely once - at the origin;
2. The equations describe two lines that are not distinct (they are the same), so we have an entire line of solutions;
3. One equation is a line while the other has both coefficients zero, i.e. is $0 = 0$, so once again there is a line of solutions;
4. Both equations reduce to $0 = 0$, so every $x, y$ is a solution.